# Dynamic Entity Reference - missing core key in info.yml

Tags: drupal-8

**Suddenly receiving this error on a Drupal 8 site:**

> Missing required keys (core) in >modules/contrib/dynamic_entity_reference/dynamic_entity_reference.info.yml

This is a core module (loaded through composer within docker) so I can see the module's info.yml file but even adding the key manually doesn't seem to have any affect.

Has anyone else had this error and any idea how to fix?

Many thanks in advance

**Drupal core version in composer.json:**

"drupal/core": "8.7.1",

**info.yml file:**
/var/www/html/web/modules/contrib/dynamic_entity_reference/dynamic_entity_reference.info.yml:

```
type: module
description: 'Provides an entity reference field that can reference multiple entity types.'
package: Field types
core_version_requirement: ^8 || ^9
dependencies:
  - drupal:field
test_dependencies:
  - drupal:field_ui
  - drupal:language
  - drupal:locale
  - drupal:node
  - drupal:taxonomy

#Information added by Drupal.org packaging script on 2019-11-06
version: '8.x-2.0-alpha10'
project: 'dynamic_entity_reference'
datestamp: 1573073895
```

Answer (score 0):

The module you have installed is compatible with Drupal 8.8-alpha1 compatibility. You need to install lower version of this module (8.x-1.7 released 31 March 2019) which is compatible with Drupal 8.7.x.

https://www.drupal.org/project/dynamic_entity_reference